# How to make a carousel using pure JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been designing a web page and I need a slider like [this](http://www.themesindustry.com/html/riwa/index5.html). How would I go about that? It's a beautiful transition, but I'm not sure how I would go about implementing it in JavaScript and CSS. Can some one please point me in the right direction?

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OpOY.png) in which there are three images in a slider.

Answer (score 4):

The name for what you called "slider" is **Carousel**.

If you are new to web development. I would suggest you use Bootstrap,

http://getbootstrap.com/

You can easily implement a Carousel using the build JavaScript component.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

If you do NOT want to introduce any dependency to your exist project, check out this PureJSCarousel project on GitHub,

https://github.com/vadymshymko/PureJSCarousel

Demo is here,

https://vadymshymko.github.io/portfolio/purejscarousel/

Comment: I cant use bootstrap. im developing this with using just css and html. :(

Comment: What can you use? Vanilla (pure) JS and CSS? I think its a good question.

Comment: yes. i will use js and css.

Comment: I have updated the answer and found you an no dependency lib. You can refere to its implementation and write your own carousel if you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I helped a lot to me. <3

Comment: No problem please accept the answer if you think it is helpful. :D